# Running powershell wihtin standard cmd with parameters?

Tags: powershell

I have downloaded the dotnet installer PS1 script file from [here](https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.ps1).

I wish to run it, and MS recommended:

> dotnet-install.ps1 -Channel 7.0 -Runtime aspnetcore

Okay, but I have to run this in a non-powershell "cmd", so I'll have to specify "powershell":

```
powershell ./dotnet-install.ps1 -Channel 7.0 -Runtime
UnauthorizedAccess

powershell ./dotnet-install.ps1 -Channel 7.0 -Runtime -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
UnauthorizedAccess

powershell -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned ./dotnet-install.ps1 -Channel 7.0 -Runtime
MissingArgument
```

How can I write this command to be able to run?

And how can I write if "dotnet-install.ps1" contains whitespace in its path?

Comment: You need to run "Dosbox as an Admin.  Try right click Dosbox shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I meant a pure (non-powershell) "cmd", and not DosBox specifically.

Comment: Still need to run As Admin.  From Start Button, type cmd and then select Run As Admin.

Comment: @jdweng, DOS, with its `command.com` console shell (command processor), was the foundation of a long-obsolete line of Windows versions ending with Windows ME. The current line of Windows operating systems, dating back to Windows NT, uses `cmd.exe` as its console shell; while its batch language is compatible with `command.com`'s, its technological foundation is different. In other words: DOS plays no part in modern Windows systems, and discussing the latter in terms of DOS is both incorrect and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

To run the installation script from `cmd.exe` *with elevation* (as admin) - which will invariably prompt for confirmation / ask for administrator credentials - try the following:

```bash
powershell.exe Start-Process -Verb RunAs powershell.exe '-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoExit -File ./dotnet-install.ps1 -Channel 7.0 -Runtime aspnetcore'
```

If your `.ps1` script file path contains *spaces*, enclose it in `\"...\"` (sic); e.g.,

`\"C:\path with spaces\dotnet-install.ps1\"`

Note that the elevated script invariably runs in a *new window*; the `-NoExit` CLI option in the nested `powershell.exe` call keeps that window open after the script terminates, which allows you to inspect output.

You may add `-Wait` to the `Start-Process` call above to make the calling `cmd.exe` shell wait for new window to close.

See also:

- [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe), the Windows PowerShell CLI.
- PowerShell's [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) cmdlet, which allows launching processes with elevation via 
  `-Verb RunAs`.